# JS: Push to array and update select without getting duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am populating a SELECT with an array. The array contains strings with employee-names.

I want to be able to add a new employee name in the array and then update the SELECT. I've made this, but I keep getting duplicates as I call the function. I kind of understand why, but I haven't quite figured out yet how to make this code better so that I only add the one employee name that is written in the text input.

I don't want to have a function that removes all duplicates, as I think it should  be possible to have several employees with the name "John".

My HTML:

```
<section id="sidebar">
    <form onSubmit="return false">
        <label for="Name">Name:</label>
        <input id="nameInput" type="text" value="Your name here..." name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add to list" name="Add" onClick="addToArray();"><br>
        <label for="Default">List over employees:</label>
        <select id="employeeSelect">
        </select>
    </form>
</section>
```

My JS:

```
var employeeList = ['Sarah', 'Louse', 'Dan', 'John', 'Peter'];

function listEmployees(){
    var select = document.getElementById('employeeSelect');

    for (var i = 0; i < employeeList.length; i++)
    {
        var option = employeeList[i];
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.textContent = option;
        newOption.value = option;
        select.appendChild(newOption);
    }
}

listEmployees();

function addToArray(){
    var txtbox = document.getElementById('nameInput');
    var value = txtbox.value;

    employeeList.push(value);
    listEmployees();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `listEmployees()` (which adds, and re-adds, *everything* in your list) each time a new name is added.

I'd move the add-a-new-`option` code out to its own function. Call it for each name in the original list, then call it again when a new name is added.

```js
var employeeList = ['Sarah', 'Louse', 'Dan', 'John', 'Peter'];

function addEmployee(name) {
  var select = document.getElementById('employeeSelect');

  var newOption = document.createElement("option");
  newOption.textContent = name;
  newOption.value = name;
  select.appendChild(newOption);
}

function listEmployees() {
  for (var i = 0; i < employeeList.length; i++) {
    addEmployee(employeeList[i])
  }
}

listEmployees();

function addToArray() {
  var txtbox = document.getElementById('nameInput');
  var value = txtbox.value;

  employeeList.push(value);   // update the list
  addEmployee(value);         // update the select
}
```

```html
<section id="sidebar">
  <form onSubmit="return false">
    <label for="Name">Name:</label>
    <input id="nameInput" type="text" placeholder="Your name here..." name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add to list" name="Add" onClick="addToArray();">
    <br>
    <label for="Default">List over employees:</label>
    <select id="employeeSelect">
    </select>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Appreciate it! This works well, and has way better logic :)